# Fetching the URL parameters with PHP after IIS URL rewrite

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

I have a PHP website,

e.g.
http://www.test.com/rewrite-test/s/z2SZhBL

This was previously on Apache which had a rewrite rule to trap the "z2SZhBL" using the `$_GET['id']`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I need to move this website onto IIS and I need to get the URL rewrite rule working. I have tried these examples.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

So in the folder "rewrite-test" I have an index.php which is echoing out the `$_GET` **variables** and there are no get variables coming back they are all empty.

I can get the variables using this workaround.

```
$params = explode( "/", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL'] );
print_r($params);
```

Is this best solution?

Comment: your just asking an opinion?

Comment: Well I am wondering if this is the correct way to retrieve the variables after they are rewritten, it feel like what I have done might be a hack/workaround should the variable not be obtainable via the $_GET, perhaps what I have done is correct.

Comment: Just import your .htaccess file to your URL Rewriter. There is a small link to this wizard. All the same rules  and techniques can be used. IIS will capture and rewrite it to the `index.php?id=$1` so you can continue to use `$_GET`.

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

IIS Manager has a good Import Rules tool. See full walk through here: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules

1. Open URL Rewrite
2. In Actions Pane, click **Import Rules**
3. Browse to your .htaccess file (Or Copy/Paste them in)
4. Review the Converted Rules
5. Rename the rule as desired
6. Click Apply Link to save the converted rules

Comment: My question was more about how do you get the variables once you have the rule set up, at the moment I am using

$params = explode( "/", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL'] );

Comment: If the rule is working properly, you would use `$_GET['id']` as you had before. Both will work, just seems like a lot of work to explode the URL. Plus you then have no index on the data you get.